# CSS Body unscrollable?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I've put:

```
body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

But I can still use my Middle Button to scroll down the page. Is there any fix for this?

I've also tried to search for the jQuery middle mouse button scroll event but didn't find anything.

Comment: Try using `html, body` as the selector and adding `margin: 0;`.

Comment: try to catch scroll event instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use overflow-y instead. Like this

```
body {
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're still able to scroll, the issue may not be the `body` tag, but the `html` tag taking up more than 100%, try this as well, it resolved a similar issue for me:

```css
html {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent middle mouse clicks, so you wont be able to scroll:

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e){
switch(e.which)
{
    case 2:
        //middle Click
        return false;
    break;
}
  return true;// to allow the browser to know that we handled it.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use css reset, or:

```
*{margin:0;}
```